# Combination of primefaces' menus

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm wondering if it was possible to combine different types of primefaces' menus. Basically I wanna have a regular menu but one of the submenues should be tiered. Is this possible and if so, how it is possible?

Edit: the menu should look somewhat like this:

[image]
<sub>(source: [picfront.org](http://www9.picfront.org/picture/CAoaNv6kS/thb/sketch.png))</sub>

Thanks nikolaus

Answer (score 0):

Look at the examples http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/menu.jsf. Just add separator where you need it.

//edit

First example is a tiered menu with multiple submenus nested.

Comment: thx, but how would a separator help me that case? Or do you mean using it just for layout reasons?

Comment: What do you mean by "tiered menu". If it is a meny splitted in sections as in the example above - you need separator just for layout reasons. If you mean menu with several "tiers" of submenus - just use nested submenus as in the fist example here :  http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/menu.jsf

Comment: well, using a tiered menu solely isn't a problem but I'd rather like to use a combination of the two different types. I'll attach a sketch of what i want. Thanks